# How to update properties view with a custom model when selection changes in project explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a plugin project that should take some data from a server when a file is selected in project explorer. After this data is taken, the properties view should be fired by the project explorer and the data taken from the server should be displayed.

I tried the following tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

I don't know how to fire the properties view on project explorer selection changing.

```
   public class TodoAdapterFactory implements IAdapterFactory {

    public Object getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class adapterType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         if (adapterType== IPropertySource.class && adaptableObject instanceof Todo){
              return new TodoPropertySource((Todo) adaptableObject);
            }                   
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Class[] getAdapterList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {
                IPropertySource.class
                };
    }
}
```

In the functions above, the properties view is fired only if I select the model in another view.

How should I create the linkage between the project explorer and properties view ?

Comment: The Properties View should already be responding to selection changes in the Project Explorer.

Comment: Yes, it responds to selection changes in the workbench...but how can I add other properties to the existing ones ? (the existing ones like size, name, path....)

Comment: Since the Project view is using a tabbed property page you can use the `org.eclipse.ui.tests.views.properties.tabbed.propertySections` extension point to add a tab, but using a different property source with this looks difficult.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how should look like the class that will contribute with another tab ? When I extend a class with AbstractPropertySection eclipse doesn't ask to add unimplemented methods.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Project view is using a tabbed property page you can use the `org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertySections` extension point to add a tab.

The following is the code for the existing properties tab used by the Project view. It just uses `PropertySheetPage` - you would have to fix this to use a different `IPropertySource`.

```
public class AdvancedPropertySection extends AbstractPropertySection {

    protected PropertySheetPage page;

    public void createControls(Composite parent,
            final TabbedPropertySheetPage atabbedPropertySheetPage) {
        super.createControls(parent, atabbedPropertySheetPage);
        Composite composite = getWidgetFactory()
            .createFlatFormComposite(parent);
        page = new PropertySheetPage();

        page.createControl(composite);
        FormData data = new FormData();
        data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
        data.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        data.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
        data.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        page.getControl().setLayoutData(data);

        page.getControl().addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {

            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
                atabbedPropertySheetPage.resizeScrolledComposite();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setInput(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
        super.setInput(part, selection);
        page.selectionChanged(part, selection);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();

        if (page != null) {
            page.dispose();
            page = null;
        }

    }

    public void refresh() {
        page.refresh();
    }

    public boolean shouldUseExtraSpace() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can find only org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertySections in my extensions lists....is it the same with org.eclipse.ui.tests.views.properties.tabbed.propertySections ?

Comment: Sorry should be org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertySections

Comment: I saw that package explorer has only one category "Info" and the properties view for package explorer isn't tabbed in the same way as for project explorer. How could I add there another property also ?

Comment: I don't know of any mechanism to change what Package Explorer shows for anything that already has an IPropertySource